# Count number of lines in a file with `latex3`

Tags: external-files, latex3, xparse

How to Count number of lines in a file with `latex3`?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
Line first
Line second
...
Line last
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% variables


% user level commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\nlines}{ m }
 {

    % some  code

 }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\nlines{\jobname.dat} % print integer value = number of lines in \jobname.dat

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello. I understand your question, but not your MWE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the (experimental) file reading loop

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
Line first
Line second
...
Line last
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% variables

\ior_new:N \g__sergiokapone_count_ior
\int_new:N \l__sergiokapone_count_int

% user level commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\nlines}{ m }
 {
    \ior_open:Nn \g__sergiokapone_count_ior {#1}
    \int_zero:N \l__sergiokapone_count_int
    \ior_map_inline:Nn \g__sergiokapone_count_ior
      { \int_incr:N \l__sergiokapone_count_int }
    \int_use:N \l__sergiokapone_count_int
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\nlines{\jobname.dat}

\end{document}
```

Notice that the file has four lines here: there is a blank line at the end for the file. One might pick up on such lines ...

Comment: Hey I am just checking this solution. I am very new to LaTeX3 programming and I have the following question. Why did you choose the scope for the io variable global but for the int variable local?

Comment: @Franz Read/write streams are always global, as you can't 'locally read/write' a file.

Comment: Got it. One more quick question: Would using \ior_close:N at the end of \nlines improve the code in any way?

Answer (score 4):

This is very easy with LuaTeX because Lua comes with a file iterator.  Bonus: This is fully expandable.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
Line first
Line second
...
Line last
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\nlines[1]{%
  \directlua{
    local ctr = 0
    for _ in io.lines([[#1]]) do
        ctr = ctr + 1
    end
    tex.sprint(ctr)
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\edef\x{\nlines{\jobname.dat}} \x

\end{document}
```